# How do we compute the mean time spent in transient states of a Markov Chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Let $X=\{X_n\}$ be a finite state Markov Chain with the state space $S = \{0,1,2,...,N\}$ such that all the states are transient. The following is the transition matrix.

$$ P = \left[\begin{matrix} p_{00} & p_{01} & ... & p_{0N} \\  p_{10} & p_{11} & ... & p_{1N} \\ \vdots & \vdots & ... & \vdots  \\p_{N0} & p_{N1} & ... & p_{NN} \end{matrix} \right] $$

Let $s_{ij}$ be the  expected number of time periods the MC is in
state $j$, given that it starts in state $i$. Then in most of the text books they directly say by conditioning on the initial transition, we get:

$$
s_{ij} = \delta_{ij} +\sum_{k=0}^{N} p_{ik}s_{kj}
$$

In this derivation, what I understand is that:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
s_{ij} & = & E[\text{time periods spent in state j} | X_0=i]\\
& = & \sum_{k=0}^{N} E[\text{time periods spent in state j} | X_1=k,X_0=i] P(X_1=k|X_0=i)\\
& = & \sum_{k=0}^{N} E[\text{time periods spent in state j} | X_1=k] P(X_1=k|X_0=i)\\
& = &\sum_{k=0}^{N} p_{ik}s_{kj}
\end{eqnarray}
$$
So, where my argument is wrong and how we are getting $\delta_{ij}$ in the formula of $s_{ij}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks:

- The summation should be over $S$, not only over $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$.
- The term $\delta_{ij}$ rightfully counts time $0$ as a time spent at $j$ when $i=j$.
- The rest of your computations is marred by misprints ($X_0=i$ becoming $X_0=1$...) and forgets to account for time $0$ but the idea is correct: consider the Markov chain starting from $X_0=i$ and condition on the value $k$ of $X_1$.

Comment: @ Did: Thanks for your comments and I fixed the necessary things as you commented.

Comment: OK. Still some mysteries or everything is clear now?